# Set input values on receiving changed prop from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I am trying to set the change the input value to its previous redux state value. For that, I am storing each redux state as history node. When a user presses ctrl+z in the form, my action creator should fetch the previous history node and find the input value(which is being done) and set the input value. I have cross-checked whether the input component is being rerendered or not with props being changed.

*My history node is double linked list if that helps

Although the props are being changed, the input value is not getting updated.

So, I have thought of updating the input field with `componentWillRecieveProps` life cycle where I set the `ref` to input component and by accessing the ref in life cycle hook, the input value gets updated.

For basic inputs like a single field in the form, it is easy to access the `ref`. I have a field which is an array of objects consisting of 3 inputs fields. Now, if I want to access these `refs` in `componentWillRecieveProps` life cycle hook, I should set the ref for each input box which is quite complicated since the array is dynamic.

Consider the array structure as

```
persons:[
{
   firstName: 'a',
   middleName: 'b',
   lastName: 'c'
},
{
   firstName: 'd',
   middleName: 'e',
   lastName: 'f'
}
.
.
.
]
```

`**MainComponent**`

```
class MainComponent extends Component{
  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    const { title, subtitle, sponsor, email, subject } = this.props;
     if (nextProps.title !== title) {
       this.uncontrolledInputRefs.title.current.value = nextProps.title;
     }
   }

  uncontrolledInputRefs = {
    title: React.creatRef()
  }

  onKeyDown = e => {
     if(e.key == 'z' && e.ctrlKey){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.undoHistory()
     }

  }

  render(){
     return(
       <Form onKeyDown={onKeyDown}>

         <Title
            value={title}
            handleTitleChange={(e) => {
               const value = e.target.value;
               this.props.handleTitleChange(value);
            }}
            refer={this.uncontrolledInputRefs.title}
          />

         <div>
             {persons.map((person,id)=>{
                 <input value={person.firstName} handlePersonChange={e=>{
                    this.props.handlePersonChange('firstName',e.target.value,id)
                 }}/>
                 <input value={person.middleName} handlePersonChange={e=>{ 
                   this.props.handlePersonChange('middleName',e.target.value,id)
                 }}/>
                 <input value={person.lastName} handlePersonChange={e=>{
                    this.props.handlePersonChange('lastName',e.target.value,id)
                 }}/>
             })}
             <button onClick={this.addPerson}>AddPerson</button>
         </div>

       </Form>
      );
  }
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
  title: state.reducer.title,
  persons: state.reducer.persons
}

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  handleTitleChange: value => dispatch(actions.handleTitleChange(value)),
  handlePersonChange: (field,value) => 
                            dispatch(actions.handlePersonChange(field,value)),
  undoHistory: _ => dispatch(reducer.undoHistory())
}
```

**initialState**

```
initialState = {
   title: null,
   persons: [{firstName: null, middleName:null, lastName:null}]
}
```

**reducer**

```
const reducer = (state=initialState,action) => {
   switch(action.type){
      case actionTypes.CHANGE_TITLE:
         return{
            ...state,
            title: action.payload.title 
         } 
      case actionTypes.CHANGE_PERSON:
         return{
            ...state,
            [action.payload.persons[action.id].[fieldToModify]:
                                                            action.payload.value 
        } 
 }
}
```

If the problem gets resolved at the root which is without using any life cycle hook and updating the input value, the life cycle update can be skipped.

Comment: How do your reducer and initialState look like?

Comment: I have updated the reducer, please check!

Comment: Will that reducer even run? I can see a `[` at the start of `[action.payload.persons...` that isn't subsequently closed.

Comment: It was a typo, Christopher!

Comment: Please check this code sandbox! This is the far I have got through by making it a controlled component.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-input-example-45y2d
I am trying to dispatch the last the `updateField` when the user stops typing. Only the last character is updating as the user stops typing.