# How to find when user stops typing in controlled components?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-redux, controlled-component

I am trying to capture the moment when the user stops typing in the controlled input. It happens so smooth inside the uncontrolled component.

When I have tried with `setTimeout`, only the last character came as an input rest all were not inputted. I am not sure why it happened

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import "./styles.css";

class Main extends Component{
  state={}

  timeout = null;

  onChange = e => {
    this.props.handleInputChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="Main">
        <input type='text' value={this.props.val} onChange={this.onChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  val: state.reducer.val
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  handleInputChange: (val)=>dispatch(reducer.changeInput(val))
}

connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

when User stops typing, it should dispatch `changeInput` action

Comment: provide your code attempt to solve the issue, we can take a look and see what's wrong with it

Comment: Well, I have got up to this point! I am trying to dispatch `CHANGE_INPUT` action as soon as the user stops typing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-example-ii9tx

Comment: Please take a look at the above link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      store.dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_INPUT", val: value });
    }, 2000)

    // if this effect run again, because `value` changed, we remove the previous timeout
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [value])

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  )
}
```

Everytime the `value` state change, the useEffect function will run. A timeout will start, that can be cancelled if the value change again before the `setTimeout` function is executed ( after 2 seconds in my example ).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the differences between my code and your code? Are they both not one and the same except that the code you gave is written in React hooks?

Comment: Your example throw a `TypeError`, so I cannot really compare. I was hoping to get the version where you had the "only the last character came as an input rest"-problem.

Comment: I am confused with the `value`. If I receive value inside input from the reducer props, how will the code change? 
I mean `const App = (value) => ...`

Comment: `const App = ({ valueFromRedux }) => { const [value, setValue] = React.useState(valueFromRedux')`, rest is the same.

Comment: I have tried this, it works but my previous functionality breaks! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543914/set-input-values-on-receiving-changed-prop-from-redux?noredirect=1#comment101551331_57543914

Comment: another code sandbox that replicate the new issue will help me; you can also open another question for that

Comment: @Fedurkun, please check the code sandbox. As soon as the user stops typing I am trying to update the input value in reducer state. But only the last character is getting into the input box. I am not sure, why setTimeout is blocking it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-input-example-45y2d

Comment: This is much more clear sandbox I have got up to. Please look into this! 
https://codesandbox.io/s/update-the-input-when-user-stops-typing-reactredux-45y2d

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/update-the-input-when-user-stops-typing-reactredux-d037g

Comment: may I know the reason why you have to change the props to state?

Comment: you have two state there: the one that live in redux (and is updated every 500ms), and the one that's local (and that should be updated instantaneously). You want to display the instant one in the textbox, because you don't want to wait 500ms after each key press for see the result, and then every 500ms keep it in sync with the one in redux.

Comment: That sounds reasonable! However, if I ever want to set the value of the input to a different value when some actions are dispatched like undo(`ctrl+z`), what is the best possible ways to sync up the props to state?

Comment: Awesome, cool! I have used `componentWillRecieveProps` but keeping in mind that it will be deprecated from v17, I will move my logic to `componentDidMount`.

Thanks Federkun!!!! :)